# Trying to strip out unwanted text in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm making a PowerShell script which queries our Office 365 tenants and exports certain information into a .csv file. The two fields I'm struggling with are the users default email address and their assigned subscriptions. I can get the data, but not sure how to manipulate it and make it look more presentable.

```
    Get-MSOLUser -All | select firstname,lastname,displayname,islicensed,{$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId},{$_.proxyaddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*'},userprincipalname | sort FirstName | Export-Csv $directory\$tenantname\Export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

1) I've managed to get their primary email address as lower cased smtp addresses will always be aliases, but how do I strip out the "SMTP:" part?

2) Instead of "reseller-account:SKU Part Number" I was hoping to shorten this to the names we usually refer them as! Such as:

- "E3" instead of "reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK"
- "E5" instead of "reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPREMIUM"
- "ProjectPro" instead of "reseller-account:PROJECTPROFESSIONAL"
- "Visio" instead of "reseller-account:VISIOCLIENT"

Two questions really but very similar! Hope you can help.

Comment: I would prefer if you asked two different questions instead: 1. Given the string "smtp:foo@foo.com" how can I strip "smtp:"? 2. Given a list of string replacement values how can I change a target string with them? Please not how most of your context is not relevant to the question but only to you. You can find more advice of this sort [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: as an example for 1. `"SMTP:yourString" -replace "SMTP:", ""`

Answer (score 1):

To Achieve that you can use [Calculated Properties](https://workingsysadmin.com/calculated-properties-in-powershell/) along with a small function to convert the SkuId's to a Friendly name and using `-replace` to remove the SMTP part , I've Created for you a simple function for the conversion, you can add other products just like i did:

The Microsoft Product Name/SKU's list can be found in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-service-plan-reference)

```
function Convert-SkuIdToFriendlyName
{
Param(
[string]$SkuId
)
    switch ($SkuId)
    {
        {$SkuId -match "ENTERPRISEPACK"} {return "OFFICE 365 ENTERPRISE E3"}
        {$SkuId -match "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM"} {return "OFFICE 365 ENTERPRISE E5"}
        default { 'Unknown' }
    }
}
```

Then use a Calculated properties to replace the 'SMTP' part and convert the SkuId:

```
Get-MSOLUser -All | 
Select firstname,lastname,displayname,islicensed,
@{N="License";E={Convert-SkuIdToFriendlyName $_.Licenses.AccountSkuId}},
@{N="Email";E={$_.proxyaddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*' -replace 'SMTP\:'}},userprincipalname | 
Sort FirstName
```

Comment: Thank you this is just about perfect. Can I ask for one small adjustment please on the license side (I've tried working it out but can't!) The code only displays one license, even if the user has multiple assigned. For example, one person could have "{reseller-account:MCOPSTN1, reseller-account:MCOEV, reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK}" But will only get one of these shorted SkId's with the script. How do I get it so they can have "E3, Domestic Calling Plan, Microsoft Phone System" etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hashtable as a lookup table for the wanted translations like so:

```
# create a hash with the desired translations.
# below are just the examples from your question. You need to fill in the rest..
$Licenses = @{
    "ENTERPRISEPACK" = "E3"
    "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM" = "E5"
    "PROJECTPROFESSIONAL" = "ProjectPro"
    "VISIOCLIENT" = "Visio"
}

Get-MSOLUser -All | 
    Select-Object firstname,lastname,displayname,islicensed,userprincipalname,
                  @{ Name = 'License'; Expression = { $Licenses[$(($_.Licenses.AccountSkuId) -replace '^.+:', '')] }},
                  @{ Name = 'PrimaryEmailAddress'; Expression = { ($_.proxyaddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*') -replace "SMTP:", "" }} | 
    Sort-Object FirstName | Export-Csv $directory\$tenantname\Export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

In order to get all licenses a user can have listed, the code could be extended to:

```
# create a hash with the desired translations for the license plans.
# below are just the examples from your question. You need to fill in the rest..
$Licenses = @{
    "ENTERPRISEPACK" = "E3"
    "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM" = "E5"
    "PROJECTPROFESSIONAL" = "ProjectPro"
    "VISIOCLIENT" = "Visio"
}

# this calculated property returns all (translated) licenses per user as comma delimited string
$userLicenses = @{
    Name = 'Licenses'
    Expression = {
        $result = @()
        foreach($lic in $_.Licenses) {
            $result += $Licenses[$(($lic.AccountSkuId) -replace '^.+:', '')]
        }
        $result -join ', '
    }
}

Get-MSOLUser -All | 
    Select-Object firstname,lastname,displayname,islicensed,userprincipalname,$userLicenses,
                  @{ Name = 'PrimaryEmailAddress'; Expression = { ($_.proxyaddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*') -replace "SMTP:", "" }} | 
    Sort-Object FirstName | Export-Csv $directory\$tenantname\Export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @KDD I have edited my answer to get all licenses for a user as comma separated string in the output.